# How to subset a dataframe that with a condition on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to get a subset of it where one column is contained in a list and the other column contains a word.

Context:
[image]

The table above is a sample of the dataframe I am working with, I am trying to subset the dataframe based on names that are contained in a list. I also want to subset it further by getting texts that contained 'named'

A sample of the code I use is:

```
names = ['a', 'an', 'my', 'by', 'mad', 'very', 'just', 'quite', 'one', 'actually', 'life', 'light', 'officially','his', 'old', 'this', 'all','the']
archive[archive['name'].isin(names)]['text'].str.contains('named')
```

But the code above returns a boolean series. I am trying to get a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain both conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
archive[archive['name'].isin(names) & archive['text'].str.contains('named')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
archive[archive['name'].isin(names) & archive['text'].str.contains('named')]
```